# App works fine on emulator, sends data to the server but crashes on devices

Tags: android, crash

Following is the code for reference:

The data goes into the database locally, I replicated it on server, to access the app from my device, which uses API level 23, which is the target sdk in my gradle file as well.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.enter_sugarcane_details_layout);

        final EditText etyear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textYear);
        final EditText etSpecies = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textSpecies);
        final EditText etPlantingDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textPlantingdate);
        final EditText etPlantingArea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textPlantingarea);
        final EditText etProduction = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textProduction);

        final EditText etExpectedAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textExpectedAmount);
        final EditText etSabhasadpart = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textSabhasadpart);
        final EditText etWhere = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textWhere);
        final EditText etDistance = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textDistance);
        final EditText ettransportmode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.texttransportmode);
        final EditText ettransportcost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.texttransportcost);
        final EditText etothersupply = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textothersupply);

        final Button bSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSavedetails);

        bSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String year = etyear.getText().toString();
                final String species = etSpecies.getText().toString();
                final String pdate = etPlantingDate.getText().toString();
                final int parea = Integer.parseInt(etPlantingArea.getText().toString());
                final int production = Integer.parseInt(etProduction.getText().toString());

                final int expamt = Integer.parseInt(etExpectedAmount.getText().toString());
                final String sabhasadpart = etSabhasadpart.getText().toString();
                final String where = etWhere.getText().toString();
                final int distance = Integer.parseInt(etDistance.getText().toString());
                final String transportmode = ettransportmode.getText().toString();
                final int transportcost = Integer.parseInt(ettransportcost.getText().toString());
                final String othersupply = etothersupply.getText().toString();

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        System.out.println(response);
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(EnterSugarcaneDetails.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                                EnterSugarcaneDetails.this.startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(EnterSugarcaneDetails.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Details were not updated")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                DetailsRequest detailsRequest = new DetailsRequest(year, species, pdate, parea, production, expamt, sabhasadpart, where, distance, transportmode, transportcost, othersupply, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(EnterSugarcaneDetails.this);
                queue.add(detailsRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add stack trace to get the crash cause.

Comment: Also post your crash logs!

Comment: @Pooja pleas post your log here

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.tonikamitv.loginregister, PID: 7109
                  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:533)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
                      at com.tonikamitv.loginregister.EnterSugarcaneDetails$1.onClick(EnterSugarcaneDetails.java:58)at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)

Comment: EnterSugarcaneDetails.java:58 -> the position where the cursor halts when i click here -> final int parea = Integer.parseInt(etPlantingArea.getText().toString());

Comment: I have declared it as int.. still this issue.

Answer (score 0):

menifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

also register the

> UserAreaActivity.class register into your menifest

yourActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.enter_sugarcane_details_layout);

    final EditText etyear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textYear);
    final EditText etSpecies = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textSpecies);
    final EditText etPlantingDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textPlantingdate);
    final EditText etPlantingArea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textPlantingarea);
    final EditText etProduction = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textProduction);
    final EditText etExpectedAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textExpectedAmount);
    final EditText etSabhasadpart = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textSabhasadpart);
    final EditText etWhere = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textWhere);
    final EditText etDistance = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textDistance);
    final EditText ettransportmode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.texttransportmode);
    final EditText ettransportcost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.texttransportcost);
    final EditText etothersupply = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textothersupply);


    final Button bSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSavedetails);
    if(isNetworkConnected)
    {

    bSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String year = etyear.getText().toString();
            final String species = etSpecies.getText().toString();
            final String pdate = etPlantingDate.getText().toString();
            final int parea = Integer.parseInt(etPlantingArea.getText().toString());
            final int production = Integer.parseInt(etProduction.getText().toString());

            final int expamt = Integer.parseInt(etExpectedAmount.getText().toString());
            final String sabhasadpart = etSabhasadpart.getText().toString();
            final String where = etWhere.getText().toString();
            final int distance = Integer.parseInt(etDistance.getText().toString());
            final String transportmode = ettransportmode.getText().toString();
            final int transportcost = Integer.parseInt(ettransportcost.getText().toString());
            final String othersupply = etothersupply.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    System.out.println(response);
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(EnterSugarcaneDetails.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                            EnterSugarcaneDetails.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(EnterSugarcaneDetails.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Details were not updated")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            DetailsRequest detailsRequest = new DetailsRequest(year, species, pdate, parea, production, expamt, sabhasadpart, where, distance, transportmode, transportcost, othersupply, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(EnterSugarcaneDetails.this);
            queue.add(detailsRequest);
        }
    });}else{
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"chec your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}

private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

  return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
 }
```

Comment: I did register into the app using the same code, and this is the next activity after logging into the app.  I have added all of the above you mentioned in the manifest!

Comment: can u send me the issue